# Accessing an external service from a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kind

Does a pod need special permission to access an external service.  I have an external service defined, and when I ssh into the pod and do a simple curl against the external service I get an error message saying `access Denied.`  This is how I define the external service (elastic search database running on my host machine)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: elasticlocal
spec:
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 9200
          targetPort: 9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: elasticlocal
subsets:
    - addresses:
        - ip: 172.17.0.1
      ports:
        - port: 9200
---
```

Now when I ssh into the pod and run `curl http://elasticlocal:9200` I get an access denied error.  I am running a k8s cluster on `Kind`.  From what I know `172.17.0.1` exposes localhost on kind.  I initially though this is an RBAC issue, but now I am not sure.

Comment: Is this a network connection refused or the elasticsearch denied your curl call as you didn't specify --user? Will be good if you paste the complete error message to your question.

Comment: did you try [egress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)?

Comment: pls add -v in your curl command, and provide us the full log. I guess it's permission issue, not network issue.

Comment: this is what I get with `curl http://elasticlocal:9200 -v`   

*   Trying 10.96.86.55:9200...
* connect to 10.96.86.55 port 9200 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to elasticlocal port 9200: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to elasticlocal port 9200: Connection refused

Comment: Based on the logs, It's able to resolve the domain name, "connection refused" means you cannot connect to that IP/port. Where is the pod you do ssh, and where is the elastic pod? Can you try to expose it with service nodeport?